# Query using like to retrieve field value with additional parameters

Tags: mysql

I have the followimng tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mod_music_periods` (
  `id` int(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `the_in` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `period` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `period` (`period`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mod_music_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `teaser` text,
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `style` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mod_music_entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `teaser` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `description` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `song_yr` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_name` varchar(250) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `active` enum('1','0') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `priority` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `period_id` char(150) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` char(150) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

1. When saving to mod_music_entries we allow an entry/record to have more than one "period_id" and "category_id".
2. A "mod_music_entries.period_id" field uses the mod_music_periods.id field enclosed in "b" and "e" characters plus a "/n". e.g. b1e /n b2e/n b3e/n   .. e.t.c
3. A "mod_music_entries.category_id" field uses the mod_music_category.id field enclosed in "b" and "e" characters plus a "/n". e.g. b1e /n b2e/n b3e/n   .. e.t.c

I need to select  mod_music_entries records but group first in mod_music_category.category then for each group of the later as a subgroup i need to group in mod_music_periods.period.

somthing like:

//Write Category one only if it has something in mod_music_entries.category_id

1. mod_music_category.category

   //Write this period only if there is something in mod_music_entries.period_id

   ```
     a) mod_music_periods.period

             i) mod_music_entries.name

             ii) mod_music_entries.name

      b)mod_music_periods.period

             i) mod_music_entries.name

             ii) mod_music_entries.name
   ```

//Write Category two only if it has something in mod_music_entries.category_id

1. mod_music_category.category

   //Write this period only if there is something in mod_music_entries.period_id

   ```
       a) mod_music_periods.period

             i) mod_music_entries.name

             ii) mod_music_entries.name

       b)mod_music_periods.period

               i) mod_music_entries.name

               ii) mod_music_entries.name
   ```

Comment: Could you clarify your question ? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Alexendre, am trying to select records from mod_music entries grouped by category_id the followed by a grouping using period_id.

Comment: Alexendre, am trying to select records from mod_music_entries grouped by category_id then followed by a grouping using period_id. The titles of the group names are collected from the mod_music_category table and mod_music_periods table. I should only display groups where mod_music_entries has those category_id and period_id. NOTE: the category_id and period_id is an array of b1e/nb2e/n that is the id collected from the mod_music_category and the mod_music_periods are enclosed using a "b" and an "e" to allow many id collected in one record.

Comment: That's still not a question. You're only telling me what you want to do. What do you want to know ******precisely****** ? What have you tried that did not work ?

Comment: I solved the problem: like this: SELECT DISTINCTROW p.id AS pid, p.the_in, p.period, p.priority
FROM mod_music_periods AS p, mod_music_entries AS e
WHERE e.period_id LIKE CONCAT( '%b', p.id, 'e%' ) ORDER BY p.priority ASC;   The issue was if i included the fields of mod_music_entries, it Showed more records than i expected. i expected 3 rows to be returned but it was returning over 10. When i removed those fields from mod_music_entries it worked. So i had to a do an inner loop with another query to do the same thing for the other table as well.

Answer (score 0):

something like this? [sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1361/1/0)

using `LIKE` and `CONCAT('%b',[some_id_of_your_choice],'e%')`

Comment: It works in your example. but how would you loop through them using the category_id and period_id?

Comment: Ignore above comment. Is it possible to SELECT DISTINCTROW ? its not working when i try that. Otherwise what i want to achieve is Loop through the results and display one entry name at time.

Comment: Still that example doesn't work when category_id and period_id are different values for one entry. Check your example at sqlFiddle, the entry 1 does not show up on NAME column...